# How to build Poisson autoregression model

Tags: r, smoothing

I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` object in R with about 3000 polygons and associated data. I have columns of expected and observed cases. For the moment, I don't have any covariates.

I'd like to perform spatial smoothing. I have used functions such as `empbaysmooth()`, `lognormalEB()`, `EBlocal()` from the `DCluster` package but have not been happy with the results.

Therefore I would like to do a conditional autoregression using `spautolm()` - I would like to model a Poisson model of observed versus expected with neighbour weighting.

I cannot figure out how to specify such a model. How do I specify merely a Poisson model for the `spautolm` command with no covariates?

Or am I barking up the wrong tree altogether?

Comment: All models have an implicit (constant) covariate whose name is "1", which may be mentioned explicitly as in `y ~ 1`.  An example appears near the bottom of p. 12 at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/vignettes/sids.pdf.  Is this what you mean, or have I misinterpreted?

Comment: Honestly...I'm not sure. But I hadn't seen the link before and it looks interesting. Thanks I'll have a good read of it and come back here later

Comment: hi @whuber, i was reading that file - a nice find. I think my problem is that I'm rather new to R and trying to do fancy stuff straight away and I'm not so used to the r notation for formula's. Taking a cue from your post, I did some searching and found this questions & answer to be very helpful: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366755/what-does-the-r-formula-y1-mean) 
Copying the example from your link I have used `y~1` with `spautolm` to do CAR on my data. I then used     `fitted.values(y)` to get smoothed values - is that correct?

Comment: You might find chapter 11 of [An Introduction to R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf) to be helpful at this stage of your learning about `R`.

Comment: Thanks yes I found that earlier today as well and it was helpful! I would give you a green check for you original post except I don't think I can green a comment ?

Comment: @whuber would you mind to add your comment as an answer to get this question off the unanswered list.

Answer (score 1):

All models have an implicit (constant) covariate whose name is "1", which may be mentioned explicitly, as in `y ~ 1`. An example appears near the bottom of p. 12 at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/vignettes/sids.pdf.